# Walking hierarchy with curl

Tags: curl, rally

While trying to manually test the REST API with curl before moving on to a script, I'm stuck trying get a list of projects.

Using the Subscription -> Workspace -> Projects drill down flow that is evidently what we are too use, I get now projects listed. I suspect that in the REST logic I'm not in the correct context of some sort, as I have many user stories, tasks, etc on the web interface.

/slm/webservice/v2.0/Subscription

This has a Count of 1 in Workspaces pointing to

/slm/webservice/v2.0/Subscription/NUMBER/Workspaces

which under Projects of Count 5 points to:

/slm/webservice/v2.0/Workspace/NUMBER/Projects

which gives QueryResult with empty Results.

Any ideas? One would think that walking the hierarchy would be the most elementary of tasks, and written down in an example somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two endpoint examples

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/subscription/1111?fetch=workspaces
```

and

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/2222?fetch=projects
```

Replace 1111 and 2222 with ObjectIDs of your subscription and one of the workspaces respectively. You may add `count` to the fetch

In WS API [v2.0 collections](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/rest_collections.jsp) are not hydrated in the same request.

I have a ruby example [here](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/ruby-rest-apps/blob/master/find_projects.rb) that shows projects in the workspace, and a C# .NET example [here](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/rally-dot-net-rest-apps/blob/master/getWorkspacesAndProjectsInSub.cs) that gets all workspaces and their projects in the subscription. The Ruby example is written with [Rally Ruby toolkit](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby), and C# is written with [Rally .NET toolkit](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET).

Answer (score 0):

[Webservices API documents](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) all the REST endpoints you need to hit.

Here's a pure cURL example:

curl -u "user@company.com:topsecret" https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/subscription?

```
{ "QueryResult" : { "Errors" : [  ],
      "PageSize" : 20,
      "Results" : [ { "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
            "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
            "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/subscription/12345678910",
            "_refObjectName" : "Rally Support",
            "_refObjectUUID" : "13eb4d62-3c4f-442e-b825-9f6786726d99",
            "_type" : "Subscription"
          } ],
      "StartIndex" : 1,
      "TotalResultCount" : 1,
      "Warnings" : [  ],
      "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
      "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0"
    } }
```

Parse subscription _ref from above, then add "/Workspaces":

curl -u "user@company.com:topsecret" "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/subscription/12345678911/Workspaces"

```
{ "QueryResult" : { "Errors" : [  ],
      "PageSize" : 20,
      "Results" : [ { "CreationDate" : "2004-11-28T17:50:59.000Z",
            "Description" : "",
            "Name" : "My Workspace",
            "Notes" : "",
            "ObjectID" : 12345678912,
            "Owner" : null,
            "Projects" : { "Count" : 4,
                "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
                "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
                "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Workspace/12345678912/Projects",
                "_type" : "Project"
              },
            "RevisionHistory" : { "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
                "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
                "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/revisionhistory/12345678915",
                "_refObjectUUID" : "272e1345-4ea4-4b62-9f23-69e90716a55e",
                "_type" : "RevisionHistory"
              },
            "SchemaVersion" : "10590c982b345c85bb0ba9b860d7fc50",
            "State" : "Closed",
            "Style" : "UserStory",
            "Subscription" : { "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
                "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
                "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/subscription/12345678916",
                "_refObjectName" : "Rally Support",
                "_refObjectUUID" : "13eb4d62-3c4f-442e-b825-9f6786726d99",
                "_type" : "Subscription"
              },
            "TypeDefinitions" : { "Count" : 67,
                "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
                "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
                "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Workspace/12345678917/TypeDefinitions",
                "_type" : "TypeDefinition"
              },
            "WorkspaceConfiguration" : { "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
                "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
                "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspaceconfiguration/12345678918",
                "_refObjectUUID" : "e32a2a43-3735-44f9-a445-cb451f755c0f",
                "_type" : "WorkspaceConfiguration"
              },
            "_CreatedAt" : "Nov 28, 2004",
            "_objectVersion" : "8",
            "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
            "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
            "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/12345678912",
            "_refObjectName" : "Program 1b",
            "_refObjectUUID" : "3b0ee50b-1055-4aa0-ae8a-f6d5a2051bff",
            "_type" : "Workspace"
          }, ... truncated
```

Grab/parse Workspace _ref from above, Add Projects collection to hydrate

curl -u "user@company.com:topsecret" https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Workspace/12345678912/Projects

```
{ "QueryResult" : { "Errors" : [  ],
      "PageSize" : 20,
      "Results" : [ { "BuildDefinitions" : { "Count" : 1,
                "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
                "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
                "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Project/12345678920/BuildDefinitions",
                "_type" : "BuildDefinition"
              },
            "Children" : { "Count" : 0,
                "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
                "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
                "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Project/12345678920/Children",
                "_type" : "Project"
              },
            "CreationDate" : "2004-07-16T22:12:12.000Z",
            "Description" : "",
            "Editors" : { "Count" : 49,
                "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
                "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
                "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Project/12345678920/Editors",
                "_type" : "User"
              },
            "Iterations" : { "Count" : 3,
                "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
                "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
                "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Project/12345678920/Iterations",
                "_type" : "Iteration"
              },
            "Name" : "Project 1",
            "Notes" : "",
            "ObjectID" : 12345678920,
            "Owner" : null,
            "Parent" : { "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
                "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
                "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/12345678921",
                "_refObjectName" : "Parent Project",
                "_refObjectUUID" : "673fbb47-73bf-4c11-8a03-62c27d4f718c",
                "_type" : "Project"
              },
            "Releases" : { "Count" : 2,
                "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
                "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
                "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Project/12345678920/Releases",
                "_type" : "Release"
              },
            "SchemaVersion" : "10590c982b345c85bb0ba9b860d7fc50",
            "State" : "Closed",
            "Subscription" : { "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
                "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
                "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/subscription/12345678910",
                "_refObjectName" : "Rally Support",
                "_refObjectUUID" : "13eb4d62-3c4f-442e-b825-9f6786726d99",
                "_type" : "Subscription"
              },
            "TeamMembers" : { "Count" : 0,
                "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
                "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
                "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Project/12345678920/TeamMembers",
                "_type" : "User"
              },
            "Workspace" : { "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
                "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
                "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/12345678912",
                "_refObjectName" : "Program 1b",
                "_refObjectUUID" : "3b0ee50b-1055-4aa0-ae8a-f6d5a2051bff",
                "_type" : "Workspace"
              },
            "_CreatedAt" : "Jul 16, 2004",
            "_objectVersion" : "3",
            "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
            "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
            "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/12345678920",
            "_refObjectName" : "Project 1",
            "_refObjectUUID" : "332061f2-40ad-47cf-b40b-8edd3962a1e6",
            "_type" : "Project"
          },
            ... truncated
```

Parse a specific Project _ref from the Projects collection output above, then:

curl -u "user@company.com:topsecret" https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/12345678920

```
{ "Project" : { "BuildDefinitions" : { "Count" : 1,
          "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
          "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
          "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Project/12345678920/BuildDefinitions",
          "_type" : "BuildDefinition"
        },
      "Children" : { "Count" : 0,
          "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
          "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
          "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Project/12345678920/Children",
          "_type" : "Project"
        },
      "CreationDate" : "2004-07-16T22:12:12.000Z",
      "Description" : "",
      "Editors" : { "Count" : 49,
          "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
          "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
          "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Project/12345678920/Editors",
          "_type" : "User"
        },
      "Errors" : [  ],
      "Iterations" : { "Count" : 3,
          "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
          "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
          "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Project/12345678920/Iterations",
          "_type" : "Iteration"
        },
      "Name" : "Project 1",
      "Notes" : "",
      "ObjectID" : 1154644,
      "Owner" : null,
      "Parent" : { "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
          "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
          "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/12345678921",
          "_refObjectName" : "Parent Project",
          "_refObjectUUID" : "673fbb47-73bf-4c11-8a03-62c27d4f718c",
          "_type" : "Project"
        },
      "Releases" : { "Count" : 2,
          "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
          "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
          "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Project/12345678920/Releases",
          "_type" : "Release"
        },
      "SchemaVersion" : "10590c982b345c85bb0ba9b860d7fc50",
      "State" : "Closed",
      "Subscription" : { "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
          "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
          "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/subscription/12345678910",
          "_refObjectName" : "Rally Support",
          "_refObjectUUID" : "13eb4d62-3c4f-442e-b825-9f6786726d99",
          "_type" : "Subscription"
        },
      "TeamMembers" : { "Count" : 0,
          "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
          "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
          "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Project/12345678920/TeamMembers",
          "_type" : "User"
        },
      "Warnings" : [  ],
      "Workspace" : { "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
          "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
          "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/12345678912",
          "_refObjectName" : "Program 1b",
          "_refObjectUUID" : "3b0ee50b-1055-4aa0-ae8a-f6d5a2051bff",
          "_type" : "Workspace"
        },
      "_CreatedAt" : "Jul 16, 2004",
      ...truncated
      "_objectVersion" : "3",
      "_rallyAPIMajor" : "2",
      "_rallyAPIMinor" : "0",
      "_ref" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/12345678920",
      "_refObjectName" : "Project 1",
      "_refObjectUUID" : "332061f2-40ad-47cf-b40b-8edd3962a1e6"
    } }
```